# TextInput value is not updated after changing state?

Tags: android, react-native, state, react-native-textinput

```
        <TextInput
            label={'Please enter your email'}
            onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text)}
            style={textInputStyle}
            value={this.state.testEmail}
        />
```

Check the function which I'm using to handle the text, where I'm appending some dummy text but it's not getting reflected.

```
onChangeText = (text, id) => {
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
                testEmail:
                text+'test'
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Here's the constructor,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        testEmail: '',
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` This method was calling anonymously which was resulting not to update the `TextInput`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextInput
  label={'Please enter your email'}
  onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
  style={textInputStyle}
  value={this.state.testEmail}
/>

onChangeText = text => {
  this.setState({
    testEmail: `${text}test`
  });
}
```

Sample snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@hannigan/nervous-tortillas).

Comment: I tried your expo project, it's working fine. But I had copied the exact same code and it's not working in my project. The issue is text gets replaced back to an empty string.